# wso2 apim role validation issue

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 IS (5.11.0) as the key manager of APIM 4.0.0). I have published a graphql API which is secured by a scope (say 'test_scope' based on a role named 'test'). I have subscribed to the API with the Default Application and have generated the keys as well. When I generate the access token with the scope ('test_scope') and invoke the secured API I'm getting the valid response even though the required role ('test') is not assigned to the user. Below is the curl command which I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

The API Manager will perform the Role-based validation during the token generation. So, if you are generating the JWT Token with a user that has the respective role assigned, then the API Manager will generate the access token with the requested scopes (that are bound to the role).

I believe that you have generated the JWT token using either Client Credentials or Password grant (not able to find the cURL in the question :)), and the token has been generated with a user who has the respective role assigned. To give more clarification, when using the Client Credentials grant, the API Manager will use the Application Owner as the user to verify the Roles and to provide the scopes. Whereas the Password grant, uses the respective username (that is sent), to verify the roles and scopes.

During the runtime, the Gateway will decode the JWT token and verifies whether the required scopes are available. If yes, the Gateway will proceed with the request, and if not it fails.

So to check the process, you can use another user in the same tenant who hasn't been assigned with the specific role and generate the Token with Password grant and invoke the API (in this scenario, the token will be generated with the default scope and not with the mentioned `test_scope`).

Hope this clarifies and provides a brief understanding of the Token generation and scope validation process.